# Are the horizon generators radial null geodesics also?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, geodesics

What I am going to ask is *probably* a result of unrigorous treatment of the submanifold in question.

### Radial Null Geodesics of Schwarzschild

So start with Schwarzschild spacetime. The metric tensor is in Schwarzschild coordinates

$$g=-f(r)dt^2+f(r)^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2),\quad f(r)=1-\frac{2M}{r}.$$

We study then *radial null geodesics*. These are curves $\gamma : I\subset \mathbb{R}\to M$ satisfying three conditions

1. They are radial, $\theta\circ\gamma,\phi\circ\gamma$ are constant.
2. They are null, $g(\gamma',\gamma')=0$.
3. They satisfy the geodesic equation.

Putting together (1), (2) and (3) we can prove that these curves are very simple in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates. They divide in two classes, ingoing and outgoing.

For the ingoing we use coordinates $(v,r,\theta,\phi)$ with $v = t+r_\ast$. Then (1), (2) and (3) implies that the curve is $\lambda \mapsto (v_0,\lambda,\theta_0,\phi_0)$.

Likewise, for outgoing we use coordiantes $(u,r,\theta,\phi)$ with $u = t-r_\ast$. Then (1), (2) and (3) implies the curve is $\lambda\mapsto (u_0,\lambda,\theta_0,\phi_0)$.

### Generators of the Horizon

Now we wish to study the surface $r = 2M$. In Schwarzschild coordinate this is not possible because this locus isn't in the domain of the chart. But it is in the domain of the Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates. We use the $(v,r,\theta,\phi)$ ones.

The horizon is $r = 2M$. Its normal one-form is $dr$. The dual vector is $\ell =\partial_v + f(r) \partial_r$. At $r=2M$ we have $\ell=\partial_v$ because $f(r)$ vanishes.

Since $\ell$ is the normal vector to the surface and since it is null at the surface, its integral lines are the generators of the null surface.

The generator thus are specified as $(r,\theta,\phi)$ constant, with $r = 2M$ which defines the surface. Plugging this into the geodesic equation we can find that the generators are $$\lambda\mapsto(4M\ln \lambda, 2M, \theta_0,\phi_0).$$

These are of course curves inside the null surface $\mathcal{H}$ but since $\mathcal{H}\subset M$ they can be seen as curves in $M$.

These curves satisfy:

1. They have constant $\theta$ and $\phi$;
2. They are null;
3. They are geodesics;

Now wait a moment, these are the three conditions for the radial null geodesics.

So it seems that the horizon generators are radial null curves.

Still, these curves have constant $r$ and have not the form which we found for radial null curves. Still, it is a fact that the three conditions *implies the form given previously*.

So what is the inconsistency here? My guess is that satisfying (1), (2) and (3) inside a submanifold doesn't imply satisfying (1), (2) and (3) on the full manifold. In particular intuitively I imagine the issue is that a geodesic on the surface is not a geodesic on the ambient space due to the constraint. But I don't know how to make this precise.

Comment: $\theta$ and $\varphi$ being constant doesn't exclude the possibility of $r$ being constant too.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the issue I have. For the first solutions $r$ itself is the affine parameter, which is clearly not constant, while for the horizon generators $r$ is constant. So the horizon generators doesn't seem to be a subset of the first solutions. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I'll check the math later, but the most obvious explanation is that you missed some solutions when working in EF coordinates. Possibly some implicit extra assumption snuck in.

Comment: *They divide in two classes, ingoing and outgoing* A horizon generator is neither ingoing or outgoing but a separatrix of those classes.

Comment: Thanks to both for the comments. With them I believe I was able to solve the issue. In fact, supposing $r$ varies is the extra assumption which made me lost a third class of solutions - those with $r$ constant. I added one answer with this worked out in case anyone ends up with the same doubt. If anything is found to be wrong, corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the comments I was able to find what is the issue. I'm posting it here, in the case anyone has the same doubt. In fact horizon generators *are radial null geodesics*. They are, in fact, a third class, separate from ingoing and outgoing. So let's work this out.

In Schwarzschild coordinates, the geodesic equation follows from the Lagrangian

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\left(-f(r)\dot{t}^2+f(r)^{-1}\dot{r}^2+r^2(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta \dot{\phi}^2)\right).$$

One needs to work out the Euler-Lagrange equations. The $t$ equation is

$$\dfrac{d}{d\lambda}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{t}}=0$$

Which actually yields one constant of motion

$$-f(r)\dot{t}=E$$

Now, the null condition is $$-f(r)\dot{t}^2+f(r)^{-1}\dot{r}^2=0.$$

Using the constant of motion we get the $r$ equation

$$\dot{r}^2=E^2\Longrightarrow \dot{r}=\pm E$$

From which it follows immediately that $r=\alpha \lambda + \beta$. Here comes the analysis, however. We have two situations here:

1. The case $\alpha\neq 0$. In this one we can reparameterize in order to get a new parameter on which $r = \lambda$. Once we substitute in the first equation we get the ingoing/outgoing null geodesics which are simpler in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates.
2. The case $\alpha =0$. Obviously is a valid solution, but now we obviously cannot reparameterize so that $r = \lambda$. Getting back to either the null condition or the $t$ equation, we see that they are satisfied if and only if at the constant $r = r_0$ one has $f(r_0)=0$. This happens only at $r = 2M$ which is not in the domain of the chart, so these solutions simply can't be studied in Schwarzschild coordinates.

   We go to Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates which covers this region and make the equations simple. I belive that it is obvious that any other chart covering this region would do. In $(v,r,\theta,\phi)$ coordinates the metric becomes $$ds^2=-f(r)dv^2+2dvdr+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$

   The geodesic equation will follow from the Lagrangian $$L=\frac{1}{2}\left(-f(r)\dot{v}^2+2\dot{r}\dot{v}+r^2(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta \dot{\phi}^2)\right)$$

   Working out the $v$ and $r$ Euler-Lagrange equations we get for the $v$ equation a constant of motion $$-f(r)\dot{v}+\dot{r}=E$$

   and for the $r$ equation we get $$\ddot{v}+\frac{1}{2}f'(r)\dot{v}^2-r(\dot{\theta}^2+\sin^2\theta\dot{\phi}^2)=0,$$

   which for radial simplifies $$\ddot{v}^2+\frac{1}{2}f'(r)\dot{v}^2=0.$$

   Now recall we set out to study the solutions which have $r$ constant. Recall these are null only if the constant is $r = 2M$. So the first equation is trivially satisfied because the LHS is zero, which is of course constant. The second equation gives the important one. Computing $f'(2M)$ we get

   $$\ddot{v}+\frac{1}{4M}\dot{v}^2=0.$$

   Solving this equation gives $v = 4M \ln \lambda$. So we get the missing solutions with $r$ constant.

   We can finally get the remaining ones working in  $(u,r,\theta,\phi)$ coordinates as well.

So in conclusion: radial null geodesics divide not in two, but three categories as pointed out in comments. Supposing that in the $r$ solution $\alpha\neq 0$ is the implicit extra assumption that snuck in as also pointed out in comments. Treating the $\alpha = 0$ case yields the remaining solutions, which clearly cannot be parameterized by $r$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the expression for $\lambda$ is?

Comment: In my notation $\lambda$ is an affine parameter for the geodesic under consideration. The relation between coordinates along the geodesic and $\lambda$ are found by solving the autoparallel equation. For ingoing/outgoing radial null geodesics it is always possible to reparameterize so that $r = \lambda$. For generators of the future horizon we have instead $v = 4M\ln \lambda$ or $\lambda = e^{v/4M}$. For generators of the past horizon there is a similar formula. Does it clarify the matter?

Comment: Yes (I assume $v$ in the exponent is the EF time coordinate). Let me ponder this. Thank you!