# Raychaudhuri equation for black holes

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, causality

Since the [Raychaudhuri equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raychaudhuri_equation) is defined only for timeline and null geodesic congruences, is it valid to use his equation to describe the null generators of the event horizon of a black hole?

Assuming that it is valid, if the black hole is stationary, the expansion parameter, $\theta=k^a_{;a}-\kappa$,will be zero. Here $k$ is a Killing vector that is timelike outside the black hole (must exist because the spacetime is stationary), while $\kappa$ is the surface gravity, defined by, $k^ak^b_{;a}=\kappa k^b$. But since $k$ is a Killing vector, its trace will be zero and hence the surface gravity of all stationary black holes will also turn out to be zero, which cannot be true. Can someone point out my mistake?

Comment: The trace of $\nabla_ak_b$ is zero, but $\theta\ne\nabla_ak^a$.

Comment: In Poisson's book that's what he has said. For non-affine paramterizations, $\theta$ equals the divergence of $k$ minus $\kappa$, the surface gravity. It's the last problem of section 2.6.

Comment: Why is $\theta=0$, for a stationary black hole?

Comment: @DrakeMarquis I had the same question. I don't fully understand why, but I think if $\theta$ were non zero, the event horizon won't be stable as there will be accumulation of geodesics. Poisson has mentioned it after equation 5.91 in his book but unfortunately it's not clear at all.

Comment: The key here is that when Poisson stated $\theta=0$ for a stationary black hole, he referred to the affinely parameterized geodesic congruences. In that case, $\nabla_ak_b$ is no longer antisymmetric, which compensates $\kappa$.

Comment: @DrakeMarquis Your answer is correct but in problem 7 of page 220 he considers a Killing vector field that is not affinely parametrized but still has a zero expansion. How should the situation be resolved then?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the draft version, which has only 190 pages. I have no access to googlebook either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95314/discussion-between-sounak-sinha-and-drake-marquis).

Comment: There is a subtilty in applying Raychaudhuri equation to the null generators of some null hypersurface. The relation $\theta=\nabla_ak^a-\kappa$ applies to the congruence define all over (some open subset of) the spacetime. In the case of the null generators $\xi^a$ of the horizon, the null $\xi^a$ is defined only on the horizon. In order to use that relation, you have to extend $\xi^a$ to some null congruence near the horizon. Although the expansion is independent of the extension, $\nabla_ak^a$ depends on it. So $\theta=\nabla_ak^a-\kappa$ cannot be used in this case.

Comment: Potentially related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/465313/are-the-horizon-generators-radial-null-geodesics-also/465461#465461