# How to define the proper time of a photon?

Tags: general-relativity, photons, spacetime, reference-frames, time

I'm writing a paper about the motion of photons near a Schwarzschild black hole. At some point there's a derivative of the Hamiltonian of the system with respect to time $\tau$. I need to explain what the proper time is $\tau$, but it's quite odd because photons don't have any proper time.

The Hamiltonian that I have is

$$H = - \left( 1-\frac{2M}{r} \right)^{-1} \frac{p_{t}^2}{2}+\left( 1-\frac{2M}{r} \right) \frac{p_{r}^2}{2}+\left( \frac{p_{ \theta}^2}{2r^2}+\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2r^2sin^2\theta} \right).$$

- So what would be the definition in this case?
- "the proper time is the time for the photon although he doesn't have one?"

Does anyone know?

Comment: Please describe the hamiltonian and give a reference. "At some point there's a derivative of the Hamiltonian of the system with respect to time Tau."

Comment: @my2cts H = - (1-2M/r)^-1 *p_{t}^2/2 + ( 1-2M/r) *p_{r}^2/2 + (p_{ \theta}^2/(2*r^2) +p_{\phi}^2/(2*r^2*sin^2(\theta))) in Latex : H = - \left( 1-\frac{2M}{r}  \right)^{-1} \frac{p_{t}^2}{2}+\left( 1-\frac{2M}{r} \right) \frac{p_{r}^2}{2}+\left( \frac{p_{ \theta}^2}{2r^2}+\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2r^2sin^2\theta} \right). The hamiltonian is the potential and kinetic energies i think

Comment: "At some point there's a derivative of the Hamiltonian..." This sounds like it's referring to some paper that you're basing your paper on. Tell us what it is.

Comment: In your comment you need to use single dollar signs to wrap around Mathjax expressions so they display properly.

Comment: Answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465136/

Comment: @BenCrowell https://www.physik.uzh.ch/~psaha/magicenv/magicenv.pdf pages 51-55

Answer (score 5):

I actually asked a question about the four velocity of the photon.

[Four-velocity vector of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480476/four-velocity-vector-of-light)

where Chiral Anomaly says:

> > Short answer: 
> >     - If the term "four-velocity" is used in the strict sense of $d x^\mu/d\tau$ where $\tau$ is the object's proper time, then four-velocity is undefined for light because the elapsed proper time is always zero ($d\tau=0$) along a lightlike worldline.
> >     - If the term "four-velocity" is used in the generalized sense of $dx^\mu/d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an affine parameter that increases monotonically along the lightlike worldline, then the four-velocity is perfectly well-defined for light.

So photons do not have a proper time, but you can use a $\lambda$ affine parameter that increases monotonically along the lightlike worldline.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that no reference frame can move at $ c $ speed of light in vacuum, so no measure of proper time can be done for a photon traveling at this speed.

Special relativity states that the elementary interval of proper time for a photon with speed $ c $ is zero.

A possible demonstration is as follows:

if $ ds $ is the elementary interval of length, the elementary interval of proper time $ d\tau $ can be defined as
$$ d\tau=\frac{ds}{c}\ \ \ \ [1] $$
Considering the elementary interval of length squared as
$ ds^2=c^2dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2=c^2dt^2-\vec{dr}^2 $,

for a photon you have $ |\frac{dr}{dt}|=c $, which leads to $ ds^2=0 $, and then with $ [1] \Rightarrow d\tau=0 $.

Hoping to have answered the question,

Best regards.